# Django I'm trying to get the latest added/edited element to the top of the page. It works with editing but not when I add new element

Tags: python, django, forms

I am getting highest integer value of model integer field and then adding +1 to it and saving it as a form. When I am adding new element I use ModelForms like that:

view.py

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'titracker/index.html'



    def get(self, request):
        form = addTicketForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form, 'tickets_to_load':Ticket.objects.all().order_by('-ticket_position')})

    def post(self, request):
        form = addTicketForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            from django.db.models import Max
            result = Ticket.objects.all().aggregate(Max('ticket_position'))
            my_list = []
            for key,value in result.items():
                my_list.append(value)
            max_pos = my_list[0]
            form.ticket_position = max_pos + 1
            form.save()
            form = addTicketForm()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('titracker:index'))
        else:
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form, 'tickets_to_load':Ticket.objects.order_by('-ticket_position')})
```

And it doesn't work, but when I don't use ModelForms it does work

html template

```
            <div class='container'>
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    {% csrf_token %}
        <input class="u-full-width" type="text" name="t_title" value="{{ticket.ticket_title}}"/>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name='t_body'> {{ticket.ticket_body}}</textarea>

           <button type="submit" value='post' class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
           <button type="submit" value='post' name='delete' class="btn btn-info">Delete</button>
            <select id='status' value='post' name='status'>
                    {% if ticket.ticket_status == 0 %}
                    <option>Open</option>
                    <option value='1'>In progress</option>
                    <option value='2'>Closed</option>
                    </select>
                        {% elif ticket.ticket_status == 1 %}
                       <option>In progress</option>
                       <option value='0'>Open</option>
                       <option value='2'>Closed</option>
                       </select>
                            {% elif ticket.ticket_status == 2 %}
                            <option>Closed</option>
                            <option value='0'>Open</option>
                            <option value='1'>In progress</option>
                            </select>             
                                    {% endif %}

     </form></div>
</div></center>
    </body>
    </html>
```

view

```
def editer(request, ticket_id):

    tick = get_object_or_404(Ticket, pk=ticket_id) 

    if request.method == "POST":
        ticket = Ticket.objects.get(pk=ticket_id)

        if request.POST.get('delete'):
            ticket.delete()
            form = addTicketForm()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('titracker:index'))
        else:
            ticket.ticket_title = request.POST.get('t_title')
            ticket.ticket_body = request.POST.get('t_body')
            ticket.ticket_status = request.POST.get('status')
            from django.db.models import Max
            result = Ticket.objects.all().aggregate(Max('ticket_position'))
            my_list = []
            for key,value in result.items():
                my_list.append(value)
            max_pos = my_list[0]
            ticket.ticket_position = max_pos + 1
            ticket.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('titracker:detail', args=[ticket_id]))
    else:
        return render(request, 'titracker/editer.html', {'ticket': tick})
```

Could someone please explain to me why this isn't working with the first form? I am really lost on that feature.

Comment: Can you share your models.py?

Comment: @Silversail https://pastebin.com/r3bJ3RvK here you go

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by saving form to new variable without actually commiting it, then adding ticket_position attribute and saving it into the database.

```
def post(self, request):
        form = addTicketForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            from django.db.models import Max
            result = Ticket.objects.all().aggregate(Max('ticket_position'))
            my_list = []
            for key,value in result.items():
                my_list.append(value)
            max_pos = my_list[0]
            position = max_pos + 1
            xpkej = form.save(commit=False)
            xpkej.ticket_position = position
            xpkej.save()
            form = addTicketForm()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('titracker:index'))
        else:
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form, 'tickets_to_load':Ticket.objects.order_by('-ticket_position')})
```